# Denying an application rights to write to the Windows Registry

Tags: windows, security, windows-registry

In Windows 7 or later, is there a way to deny a program rights to write anywhere in the registry?

Please specify to which version of Windows your answer applies.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows Vista and later, you can accomplish this by setting the [integrity level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx) of the program in question to Low or Untrusted.

One way to do this is to use the [`icacls.exe` utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(WS.10).aspx) to set the program's integrity level.  For example, suppose you want to set notepad.exe to low integrity. From an elevated command prompt, type:

```
icacls notepad.exe /setintegritylevel low
```

This prevents Notepad from affecting system level objects with a medium or high integrity level, such as system files, various Registry hives, and so on.

Depending on the program in question, this may be a very good or a *very* bad idea.

Integrity levels can be a confusing thing to understand.  Please take time to carefully review [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625957.aspx), to learn how to discover [the current integrity level](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2010/09/07/integrity-levels-and-dll-injection/), and to understand the full impact of the changes you're attempting.

Be *very* careful when doing this, as it's pretty easy to mess things up severely, especially if you're not entirely sure of what you're doing.  Make a back up, experiment on a copy, don't try this at home, the secretary will disavow all knowledge, etc., etc.

Comment: My tape recorder suddenly exploded into flames....

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but it is possible to create a situation where it would work.

You can set security settings in the registry for user accounts, but not programs.

You can also start a program as a different user. So in theory you could create a user account that can't modify, then specifically set that user to not have rights to modify that specific registry key, yet give it permission to read that key, and optionally write to other keys.

***Note that:*** *limiting access to the registry can lead to weird errors because programs usually don't check if the registry part they want to write to can actually be read, especially if you set rights in the HKEY_Current User section.*

## To set rights

Open the registry and navigate to the key where you want to change the rights. Rightclick the key (folder thingy) and choose Permissions...

From here you can give rights. Note Full Control = do everything, including: query value, set value, create subkey, enumerate subkeys, notify, create link, delete, write dac, write owner and read control.

Special permissions allow you to set individual rights. In order to do this, press the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> button.